# How to have Visual Studio recognize ANTLR4 generated code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, antlr4

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with ANTLR4 with the offical plugin. It recognizes .g4 files. I wrote a grammar file, and it seems to generate code. The generated code is placed into the `obj\Debug` folder. Also, partial classes are generated as child of the .g4 grammar file.

So, all seems to go well, except that Visual Studio does not recognize the code in `obj\Debug`. The partial classes under the g4 solution item do not resolve to the other part of the partial classes.

What is the best way to have visual studio include the generated code in `obj\Debug`?

Comment: This sounds like a bug report for the [tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) project on GitHub. The best way to get this issue resolved would be filing an issue there so we can work through it.